# Problema al hacer npm start en instalación de react

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, npm

Al instalar React, al momento de inicializar npm en la carpeta del proyecto para abrir el local host vía cmd, aparece el siguiente error:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! aprendiendoreact@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the aprendiendoreact@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-21T18_36_39_874Z-debug.log
```

Estuve leyendo varias respuestas pero ninguna me ha funcionado al momento de intentar corregir este error.

Comment: mira el log a ver que pone `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-21T18_36_39_874Z-debug.log`

Comment: parece ser que necesitas añadir CMD a las variables de entorno. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624686/get-spawn-cmd-enoent-when-try-to-build-cordova-application-event-js85

Comment: Hola, sí muchas gracias, efectivamente hacía falta añadir C:\Windows\System32 a path como nuevo a las variables de entorno

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución gracias a los comentarios de [hawks](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/357972/problema-al-hacer-npm-start-en-instalaci%C3%B3n-de-react/358437#comment644335_357972) por una parte, en la pregunta y a una [publicación similar en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28624686/3695983).

Sin embargo, es importante señalar que esto me sucedió porque tengo instalado eclipse, al instalarlo se eliminó System 32 en el path y se agregó jdk en su lugar.

Al revisar el detalle con el archivo de error, figuraba que npm estaba utilizando jdk como path, por lo cual hay que seguir la siguiente ruta

- propiedades del sistema
- variables del entorno
- editar path
- agregar C:\Windows\System32

la solución

Comment: ahí puse la ruta

Comment: Se ve genial. Te daría otro +1 pero no me deja :)